# Count missing timestamps for each distinct id of one column

Tags: sql, time-series, vertica

I have a Vertica Database in which we store timeseries data. Each timeseries corresponds to an item_id and it looks like this

```
start_date,item_id,value
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808277,16
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808289,23
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808293,18
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808312,85
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808316,19
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808367,29
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808383,24
2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000,466808446,106
```

The timestamps are in 15 minutes periods (e.g. 2019-10-01 16:15,2019-10-01 16:30, 2019-10-01 16:45). I want to count how many missing timestamps there are for each item_id.

I though of creating a temporary table with timestamps going from the minimum start_date to the maximum and then joining them to check missing timestamps.

```
SELECT ts
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-09-14 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    UNION
    SELECT '2019-10-09 17:00:00'::TIMESTAMP as tm
) as t
TIMESERIES ts as '15 minutes' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
```

The problem with joining is that it will show just one null entry if there is more than one item with missing timestamps since we are joining with the temporary table (which only has consecutive timestamps). It looks like this

```
select ts, item_id, start_date, speed from public.measure_link_aforos_inrix_15min as links right outer join
(SELECT ts
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-09-14 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP as tm
    UNION
    SELECT '2019-10-09 17:00:00'::TIMESTAMP as tm
) as t
TIMESERIES ts as '15 minutes' OVER (ORDER BY tm)) as calendar on links.start_date = calendar.ts
where start_date is null
```

How can I get a join that considers also the item_id dimension on the timeseries side? (the ts table)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the values.  I can't easily follow your table names, but something like this:

```
select ts.timestamp, i.item_id, t.value
from (<your query here for ts>) ts cross join
     (select distinct item_id from timeseries) i left join
     timeseries t
     on t.timestamp = ts.timestamp and t.item_id = i.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you count the expected row count per `item_id` or the expected row count overall for the whole time series.

```
-- Creating a table like yours, but with two rows per item_id,
-- either 30 min or 1 h 30 min apart
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE input(start_date,item_id,value)                                                                                      
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808277,16
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808289,23
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808293,18
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808312,85
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808316,19
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808367,29
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808383,24
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:15:00.000000',466808446,106
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:45:00.000000',466808277,16
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 17:45:00.000000',466808289,23
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:45:00.000000',466808293,18
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 17:45:00.000000',466808312,85
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:45:00.000000',466808316,19
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 17:45:00.000000',466808367,29
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 16:45:00.000000',466808383,24
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 17:45:00.000000',466808446,106
);

-- looking for missing rows between first and last timestamp 
-- per item id

SELECT
  item_id
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    minute
  , MIN(start_date)
  , MAX(start_date))
  //15
  + 1
  - COUNT(*)
  AS missing_count
FROM input
GROUP BY 1
;

--    item_id  | missing_count 
--  -----------+---------------
--   466808277 |             1
--   466808289 |             5
--   466808293 |             1
--   466808312 |             5
--   466808316 |             1
--   466808446 |             5
--   466808367 |             5
--   466808383 |             1

-- looking for missing rows between the all-first and all-last timestamp

WITH
expected_row_count AS (
  SELECT
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, MIN(start_date), MAX(start_date))//15
 + 1 AS expected_row_count
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  item_id
, expected_row_count - COUNT(*)
  AS missing_count
FROM input CROSS JOIN expected_row_count
GROUP BY
  item_id
, expected_row_count
;
--  item_id  | missing_count 
-- ----------+---------------
-- 466808446 |             5
-- 466808316 |             5
-- 466808312 |             5
-- 466808293 |             5
-- 466808289 |             5
-- 466808277 |             5
-- 466808367 |             5
-- 466808383 |             5
```